# Sculpting details to human head

Tags: sculpting

I have completed a human head using sculpting. I smoothed the face. Now I have to put details like skin pores, blemishes, acne etc on top. I decided to use alpha map in sculpt mode. (I think height map is not that helpful and I have no knowledge on that. Bump map is not helpful because I can't create details on a particular place. So rejected the idea of bump map and height map. Sticking to alpha map)
My computer can't handle multiresolution at this stage. So I am using dyntopo and set the image of skin pore as texture to a sculpt brush.
But my problem is head is created. With each stroke it creates some geometry, I have to smooth it and this way the details of pore is getting vanished.
What is the solution?

Comment: I'm not sure that having that much detail as real geometry is the right approach, specially if you are already hitting the limits of your hardware. You can indeed create bump maps and height maps and control what parts are affected by it (that is what UV maps are for)

Comment: @cegaton really can a bump map affect only some portion of the mesh? How to achieve that? I'm a beginner.

Comment: Please read on how to create UV maps. Something else to think about is creating parts of the object as high density meshes with the detail you need and then bake normal and bump maps to use on a lower poly mesh.

Comment: @cegaton i have created uv map and normals. But How yo create bump map on parts?